# Solaris 10 - Creating packages in $HOME

Tags: python, solaris, gnu-make, solaris-10

I'm developer and I love to code with python, the problem is most of the server in which need to deploy my packages are Solaris 10 and they don't have python upgraded, so I configured one development server as my dev environment, and I didn't have problems following my common steps

```
CC="/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -m64" CXX="/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -m64"./configure --  prefix=$HOME/.local

/usr/sfw/bin/gmake

/usr/sfw/bin/gmake install
```

When was necessary just added `CFLAGS` `CPPFLAGS` `LDFLAGS` and so, I used this way because I'm not a privileged user.

Then with those steps, I created a script to build all those packages and it works `only in this environment` but it takes a lot of time (`a little problem and not the most important`), The main problem is, after ran my script with other user `same server` I got tons of errors so it began to frustrate me, I suppose the problem is they use different paths and libraries and I can't inspect all servers to compare them, since I'm not privileged to do that.

I'm trying to discover a clear path to reuse my `local-dev` environment and install it in any environment with same Solaris 10,

I found the packages are the way to share them reducing the installation time and be sure they will be installed, it is true?

In my experience, all the package always being compiled in root paths as `/usr/local/` and I don't know if it is true.

Recently I read the http://www.sunfreeware.com/ (discontinued) deliver their packages in `$HOME/usr/local`, Regrettably, I couldn't get any source from there to looking how they did.

If I compile without prefix in my `dev-environment` and use gmake with `DESTDIR` set to `$HOME/.local/` it preserves the source to build a package right?

Using `pkgadd` install me the packages in same $HOME/.local path?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.garex.net/sun/packaging/create_pkg.html 
and here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-0406/ch6advtech-53/index.html
It should be possible to install packages in your $HOME by the means of a request script.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I read the info, and I try it, The problem was the privileges, anyway, my workaround at this time was compiled all the dependencies, I will continue research about it maybe if I build static libraries what do you think?

Comment: If you run just make && make install you do not install the package as the system wide system database is not updated. Static libraries might help but you can as well add entries to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable - i.e set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the location of your libraries either in $HOME/.profile or somewhere else.